# Google map route not found message

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps v3 API to calculate a route of 1 hour,
I calculate route of 56 min finally when I am about to calculate route for remaining 4 min
It doesn't find any route for 4 min from last calculated point in that area.

What could be a best solution to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you hit the limit for way points. *If I remember right, it's 8.*

---

**EDIT:** If it's about the timeout, then do something like this:

```
/* Before questioning way points: */
$delay = 0; // ms
if {
    // do stuff
}
else
{
    $delay = 10000; // 10 sec.
}
/* After */
usleep( $delay );
```

Comment: actually not, I have not yet cross the limit. I understand that, it doesnt find any existing path in the area where it could put the coordinate for they rest of 4 mins. May be.